# correlation of two values in one receive buffer Load runner

Tags: winsock, loadrunner

I have recorded a script in LR11.5 version using Winsocket protocol (Only protocol I was able to use to record my application). I want to correlate few receive buffers. In one such buffer I have two values to correlate, given that both are same values. Buffer is as below :-

recv buf30 136
    "&SOT&148\vF.USER\v**SK1**\vTIME.OUT.MINUTES&EOT&&START&148\v3\v999&END&&START&"
    "99\v56\v28 FEB 2016\v**SK1**\v8298,\v28 FEB 2016 16:23\vg15.0.00\vr11.000&END&"

The high lightened values are the one that I need to correlate. What should I do for this. I have used to lrs_save_param() function for correlation.

Comment: For clarity, are you trying to capture the values in the RECV buffer, or replace them?  Correlating has two functions.  The assumption here is to capture as this is a receive buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correlation API you need depends on the network protocol recorded in your script. If it uses constant offsets of fields, you can safely use **lrs_save_param**. The result of correlation would be something like this:

```
lrs_save_param("socket0", LRS_LAST_RECEIVED, "param1", 16, 3);
lrs_save_param("socket0", LRS_LAST_RECEIVED, "param2", 138, 3);
```

(Zero-based offset, length of the value.)

But if the offsets vary from run to run, the situation is more complicated: you'll have to specify boundaries for the extracted values. For instance:

```
lrs_save_searched_string("socket0", LRS_LAST_RECEIVED, "param1", "LB/BIN=\v", "RB/BIN=\v",
    2, 0, -1);
lrs_save_searched_string("socket0", LRS_LAST_RECEIVED, "param2", "LB/BIN=\v", "RB/BIN=\v",
    8, 0, -1);
```

(Left and right boundary, 1-based number of occurrence, offset from the left boundary, length, which is autodetected in this case.)

Please check [the official documentation](http://lrhelp.saas.hpe.com/en/latest/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/112000_t_corr_winsock_script_view.htm) for details.

Comment: Thank you @tserg42... This was helpful

Comment: @RakeshR, you're welcome. If any of the answers has solved your question, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This is not obligatory :).

Comment: I am new to this site. I will definitely keep this in my mind here on. Thanks :)